# Biodegradable Food Packging

Tags: recycling, food, plastic, packaging, biodegradable-waste

I am trying to figure out an application for a biodegradable packaging material a found out about. It is made from old or used potatoes or corn starch. I was thinking of using it in Pizza boxes to suck up the grease so pizza boxes can be recycled. Does anybody know any good applications for this?

Comment: I think we'd need some more information about that packaging material and its properties.

Comment: @Erik I don't know much I just read somewhere about using potato peels we could make some biodegradable food packaging. I was wondering If yall knew anything about it to help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult to make plastic from strong sugars. The trick is to make plastic from less expensive weak sugars like wood chips. One company making plastic from wood chips has given up on a quick biodegradable action because of shelf life requirements of food.

https://www.avantium.com/technologies/dawn/

Here is another link in the news:

https://www.pulpex.com/

Here is a food industry supplier with a biodegradable lining for grease:

http://www.biomasspackaging.com/no-more-soggy-food-containers-introducing-our-new-ingeo-lined-clamshells/ .

Comment: @S Spring Wow thanks for the info, that is very helpful, I am currently looking into that right now.